# Rails 3.2.1 actionmailer setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm having difficulty setting up ActionMailer on signup:

`config/initializers/setup_mail.rb`

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => "587",
 :domain               => "mail.gmail.com",
 :user_name            => "my_gmail_user_name",
 :password             => "my_gmail_pw",
 :authentication       => "plain",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
Mail.register_interceptor( DevelopmentMailInterceptor ) if Rails.env.development?
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @user = User.new( params[:user] )

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.welcome_email( @user ).deliver

      format.html{ redirect_to( @user, :notice => 'Account successfully created.' ) }
      format.json{ render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
end
```

`app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from "no-reply@myapp.com"

  def welcome_email( user )
    @user = user
    @url = "http://localhost:3000/login"
    mail( :to => user.email, :subject => 'Welcome to app' )
  end
end
```

`lib/development_mail_interceptor.rb`

```
class DevelopmentMailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    message.subject = "#{message.to} #{message.subject}"
    message.to = "mydump@email.com"
  end
end
```

I'm not getting any emails sent to my dump email in `DevelopmentMailInterceptor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gmail is anal!  Is there anyway you can use a different smtp host? I think, due to overly aggressive spam detection,  they will silently reject smpt requests that they consider 'potential spam'.  Potential Spam in your case means emails directed to be from an address OTHER than "mail.gmail.com",  which in your case is "email.com".

I think using gmail as an SMTP host for a Rails app is a loosing proposition, I use godaddy.com (smtpout.secureserver.net) for my rails apps, and have no problems.